# How to create a slide panel

Tags: java, swing, panel, slide

I try to change a layout of the panel, but there are problems, because when I change layout the components remain on the panel and there are many bags.

```
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LayoutTest extends JFrame {
public LayoutTest() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton = new JButton();

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LayoutManager tempGroupLayout = jPanel1.getLayout();
            jPanel1.setLayout(layoutManager2);
            jPanel1.getParent().validate();
            layoutManager = layoutManager2;
            layoutManager2 = tempGroupLayout;
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
            addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().
            addContainerGap(286, Short.MAX_VALUE).
            addComponent(jButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)));
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
            addComponent(jButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 442, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    layoutManager = jPanel1Layout;

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout2 = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1Layout2.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout2.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
            addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout2.createSequentialGroup().
            addComponent(jButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)));
    jPanel1Layout2.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout2.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
            addComponent(jButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 442, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    layoutManager2 = jPanel1Layout2;
    getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
    pack();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new LayoutTest().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private JButton jButton;
private JPanel jPanel1;
private LayoutManager layoutManager;
private LayoutManager layoutManager2;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the JSplitPane component. You can nest a few of them.

```
splitPane.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, new SplitPanePropertyChangeListener());

private class SplitPanePropertyChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener {    
    public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {    
        int nv = ((Integer) evt.getNewValue()).intValue();    
         if (nv == 1) { //adjust this depending on your divider location    
         setSize(new Dimension(800, 560));    
      }    
      if (nv == 221) { //adjust this depending on your divider location    
         setSize(new Dimension(1000, 560));    
      }     
   }    
}
```

Check with above code and remodel it for your requirement

Comment: I have heard about JSplitPane for this purpose, but I don`t find how to so this. May be you tell some ideas.

Comment: How I can change a view and position of Open/Close Button.