# Java Swing JPanel slide up animation?

Tags: java, swing, animation, jpanel, slideup

[image]

I have this thing and when I click on the filter arrow (it should be a up arrow I know):
- the form pannel above has to slide up slowly (and disapear)
- the green panel has to be lifted up 
- the bottom scrollpane has to slowly rise up its height (+the height of the form panel)

I am not so good with swing, how can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Regards

Comment: May be this http://java-sl.com/tip_slider.html?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a slide panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429293/how-to-create-a-slide-panel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) comes with a JXCollapsiblePanel which might be helpful. Its [demo](http://swinglabs-demos.java.net/demos/swingxset6/swingxset.jnlp) shows it in action (as taskPanes) at the left - that's the part for choosing the demos.

Comment: Never seen something like that developed in Java Swing. Very interesting the links you posted! Thank you!